# Power set-Commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

$\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$... are commutative rings because, for example, $xy=yx, x, y\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Could you give me examples for power set being commutative ring?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a set; $\wp(X)$ becomes a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) when you take intersection as multiplication and symmetric difference as addition. This ring is isomorphic to the direct product of $|X|$ copies of the two-element ring.